# Select only keys from dict with values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very long dictionary

```
mydict = {
    "6574": [],
    "3234": [1],
    "7014": [],
    "0355": [3],
    "1144": [2],
    # …
}
```

I need to get all keys that have a non-empty list.

```
mytruedict = {}
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if v:
        mytruedict[k]=v
```

I was wondering if there is a one-line approach to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
mydict = {
    "6574": [],
    "3234": [1],
    "7014": [],
    "0355": [3],
    "1144": [2]
}

print( dict((k, v) for k, v in mydict.items() if v) )
#or
print( {k: v for k, v in mydict.items() if v } )   #dict comprehension
```

**Output:**

```
{'3234': [1], '1144': [2], '0355': [3]}
```